# Cython list of class

Tags: cython

I am new on cython and I need construct a list of the classes.

The class is:

```
cdef class Acl_cy:
    cdef int s0
    cdef str s1
    cdef str s2
    cdef str s3
    cdef str s4
    cdef int s5
    cdef int s6
    cdef str s7
    cdef str s8
    cdef str s9
    cdef int s10
    cdef str s11
    cdef int s12
    cdef int s13
```

If a create a list in python `list_tmp = []` and appending the classes.
It will work but it will transform all cython classes in python object, because of this the code is slower.

Is it possible create a cython vector of the class, and use it on the for loop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cython extension classes *are* python objects, so there isn't any actual transformation going on, but your general sense is right that it could be adding indirection/overhead to the generated code.

The easiest thing you can is declare the type of the list elements you are accessing, this will generate somewhat more efficient attribute access - a full example is further below.

Outside of that, you could ditch python objects all together and use arrays of c-structs, vectors of c++-classes, etc.

```
%%cython
cdef class Acl_cy:
    cdef public int s0, s1, s2
    cdef public str st0, st1, st2
    def __init__(self, s0, s1, s2, st0, st1, st2):
        self.s0 = s0
        self.s1 = s1
        self.s2 = s2
        self.st0 = st0
        self.st1 = st1
        self.st2 = st2

def make_list():
    l = []
    for _ in range(10000):
        l.append(Acl_cy(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'))
    return l

def loop():
    cdef list l = make_list()
    cdef int sum = 0
    for itm in l:
        sum += itm.s1
    return sum

def loop_typed():
    cdef list l = make_list()
    cdef Acl_cy itm
    cdef int sum = 0
    for itm in l:
        sum += itm.s1
    return sum

# In [274]: %timeit loop()
# 1.35 ms ± 67.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# In [275]: %timeit loop_typed()
# 808 µs ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```